# The best place for mapping M->VM in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I use ASP.NET MVC 3.

I encountered at least 2 approaches for mapping Model->ViewModel on the server side:

- inside ViewModel class constructor
- inside Controller or designated mapper class

I like first approach the most as the ViewModel property declarations and its mapping are in the same place, easy to maintain and unit-test. Can anybody specify more pros and cons, or other better practice?

Answer (score 2):

ViewModels can exist independently of any database-originated model classes.

I don't recommend putting ViewModel population code inside the Controller as this it not the responsibility of the controller (and is also a maintenance nightmare).

My opinion is that mapping from ViewModel to DBModel (and vice-versa) is the responsibility of the ViewModel, so all of my ViewModel classes implement two members:

```
public static TViewModel FromDBModel(TDBModel dbModel);

public void ToDBModel(TDBModel dbModel);
```

The first is a static method that the Controller calls when returning a View. The static method constructs an instance of the ViewModel and sets its members accordingly.

The instance ToDBModel method is passed a constructed DBModel instance (either constructed by the Repository when retrieving or updating data, or constructed by the controller when inserting new data).

HTH.

EDIT: Note that many people swear by libraries such as AutoMapper (which uses reflection and other tricks to automate the DBModel<->ViewModel mapping process). I'm not a fan of auto-mapping because it takes control away from the developer and I don't see it buying me time when I have to learn how the mapper works and how to get it to map non-trivial operations. YMMV.

Comment: Interesting approach. Thanks. I also agree upon AutoMapper, it seems to make sense if you have hundreds of properties only, or want to use different sort of mappings dynamically in run-time.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tend to keep entities and view models separate such that they are unaware of each other. This is to improve encapsulation and minimize dependencies when testing the controllers and mapping itself. See [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Instead I'd write classes to perform the mappings myself (if its simple) or use AutoMapper and use that method from within the controller. For a larger systems with tens or hundreds of database entities and views, I tend to lean towards AutoMapper. Writing the mapping yourself can become very tedious and error prone.  You have to balance the value of you writing it yourself with the value such implementation gives to business.  After all, if we wanted to know everything about every framework, we'd each be writing our own version of the .NET framework.  :)

That said, there may be little benefit using view models for some systems, especially those where there is a one to one mapping between "fields" in a view and database entities [aka typical CRUD]. I usually cringe when I see that, but it is always an option given a time frame and complexity of the system.

Then there is a case when you use ASP.NET MVC to expose an API. In this case "application/json" and "text/xml" representations of your entities are just "views".  View models are often used filter sensitive and unnecessary data from that external presentation.  In this case mapping becomes rather complex due to the fact that there may be several representations (and versions thereof) for the same entity. However, this seems outside of the OP.